# Correcting wrongly generated href link in the HTML <head> and <body> of Joomla

Tags: php, joomla3.0

One of the Joomla 3 templates I use on a multilingual website generates wrong href tag links in the HTML header and also in the body. The href on all multilingual pages reads:

```
in the HEAD
    link href="https://domain/page?layout=post" rel="alternate" hreflang="en-GB" />

in the BODY
    a href="/fr/page?layout=post">
```

and should be

```
    link href="https://domain/page" rel="alternate" hreflang="en-GB" />
and
    a href="/fr/page">
```

I have currently used a temporary rewrite of the .htaccess file; however, that generated hundreds of 301 redirects and I am sure that is not a good SEO solution.

Because it will take some time for finding the origin and permanently correcting the code, I need some help with PHP to remove the string **?layout=post** and showing the correct href links in the  and .

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you need to go to Joomla settings and enable **Search Engine Friendly URLs**

And only after this you should modify **.htaccess** file.

[image: Example of Joomla settings change]

This should solve your problem, if it didn't that it is maybe as you say a template issue but then you have to look it in a template files witch take some time from you.

Answer (score 0):

this is the version I'm using.
I make it on clean php.

```
    <?php
// your full url
$url = 'https://www.shop.com/en/category/tv-video-and-audio/';
//accepted languages or site version
$langs = array(
        'en',
        'cn',
        'ru'
    );
    //function to render full page link in all languages
function renderhrefurl($url = NULL, $lang = NULL){
    $exploded = explode('/', $url);
    $exploded[3] = $lang;
    return implode('/', $exploded);
}
//set hreflang attribute data
$hreflangs = array(
    array(
        'hreflang' => 'en',
        'hrefurl' => renderhrefurl($url, 'en')
        ),
    array(
        'hreflang' => 'cn',
        'hrefurl' => renderhrefurl($url, 'cn')
        )
        ,
    array(
        'hreflang' => 'ru',
        'hrefurl' => renderhrefurl($url, 'ru')
        )
    );
    //generate result
    foreach($hreflangs as $key => $item){
        echo '
        Key: '.$key.' - lang: '.$item['hreflang'].' = '.$item['hrefurl'];
    }
    echo '
    ------- Rendered Href Langs Tags ------- ';
    //generate completed hreflangs
        foreach($hreflangs as $key => $item){
        echo '
        <link rel="alternate" hreflang="'.$item['hreflang'].'" href="'.$item['hrefurl'].'" />';
    }
    
    ?>
```

Copy this code and paste to [php compiler online](https://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/) to show how it work.
And use `strtok('Your link with get parameter', '?');` to delete get parameters!